# How to submit a complex form using Jquery's AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to submit a form using Jquery's ajax. It has got a few textboxes, some checkboxes, and a multiple options' dropdown (i.e multiple options can be selected).

Someone here told me that I can get values of all selected checkboxes using

```
$("input:checkbox[name=type]:checked")
```

Then I can loop through all the values returned by the above code, assign them to an array like this:

```
var types=new Array();

    $.each(cboxes, function()
      {
         types[types.length]=$(this).val();
      }
    );
```

And try to submit the form using this:

```
var someField=$("#someField").val();
var someField2=$("#someField2").val();
var data={field1 : someField, field2=someField2, s_types:types};
$.post("signup.php?type=p",types);
```

But that doesn't work, specifically the checkboxes don't get submitted correctly. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 13):

It's not necessary to iterate over each field to get the form values. jQuery has a method to serialize form inputs into a querystring. You can do this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "mybackend.php",
  data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
  success: function(e) { // do something on success },
  error: function(e) { // do something on error }
});
```

Remember that javascript posts always send data in UTF-8 format, so be sure you're expecting that on the backend if you plan to send text with international characters.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using a plug-in to do that. Have a look at this [form plug-in](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/). It also can integrate nicely with [validation plug-in](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

Comment: this is the best idea. It also allows you to upload files via ajax.

Answer (score 2):

The default jQuery [$.param](http://docs.jquery.com/Internals/jQuery.param) doesn't handle arrays ([by design](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/4177#comment:1)), so you can't use $.serialize as it is. Use either a plugin, like suggested in [kgiannakis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590214/how-to-submit-a-complex-form-using-jquerys-ajax/590247#590247), or overwrite the $.param function so it'll handle arrays properly:

```
function($) {
  $.param = function(a) {
    var s = [];
    if (a.constructor == Array || a.jquery) 
      jQuery.each(a, function() { s.push( encodeURIComponent(this.name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent( this.value ) ); });
    else
      for (var j in a)
        if (a[j] && a[j].constructor == Array) jQuery.each( a[j], function(){ s.push( encodeURIComponent(j) + "[]=" + encodeURIComponent( this ) ); });
        else s.push(encodeURIComponent(j) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(a[j]));
    return s.join("&").replace(/%20/g, "+");
  };
})(jQuery);
```

...and then use $.serialize, like suggested by [Danita](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590214/how-to-submit-a-complex-form-using-jquerys-ajax/590267#590267).